# How do we prove the directional derivative is given by $\nabla F(x) \cdot v = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}F(x + tv)\Big|_{t =0 }$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to prove the following equation:

$$\nabla F(\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}F(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{y})\biggr|_{t=0}$$

How do I apply chain rule to prove it? This is what I have tried so far:

[image]

I am not sure how does the red derivate come in picture? By that I mean I am dividing by "dx_1" but multiplying by "d(x_1+ty_1)" which when differentiated by t gives me y_1?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Can you please add more information what you already know about derivatives in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is what you're supposed to do. Your confusion seems to come from viewing the derivative as a fraction (which it is not), along with confusing notation. I'll rewrite it in some less ambiguous notation. If we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\supset\kern-0.7mm\to\mathbb{R}$, we'll write $\partial_jf$ for the derivative of $f$ with respect to the $j$'th argument. Then we could write the relevant special case of the chain rule as

$$(f\circ g)'(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_jf(g(x))g_j'(x),$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\supset\kern-0.7mm\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g=(g_1,\dots,g_n):\mathbb{R}\supset\kern-0.7mm\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are sufficiently nice. Then what you're doing is considering the two functions $F:\mathbb{R}^n\supset\kern-0.7mm\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g=(g_1,\dots,g_n):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, given by $g(t)=x+ty$. Noticing that

$$g_j'(t)=y_j,$$

with $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, we get from the chain rule that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}F(x+ty)
&=(F\circ g)'(t) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_jF(g(t))g_j'(t)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_jF(x+ty)y_j \\
&=\langle\nabla F(x+ty),y\rangle.
\end{align*}

Consequently, by letting $t=0$, we get that

$$\langle\nabla F(x),y\rangle=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}F(x+ty)\biggr|_{t=0}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a differentiable function. This means there exists a linear transformation $f'(x)$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ corresponding to every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(x + h) - f(x) - f'(x)h\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}} {\|h\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}} = 0
\end{align*}

In particular, if we set $h = tv$ for some direction $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$, one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\|f(x + tv) - f(x) - tf'(x)v\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}}{\|tv\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\|v\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}}\left\|\frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} - f'(x)v\right\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} = 0
\end{align*}
whence it can be deduced that:
\begin{align*}
f'(x)v = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(x + tv)\Big|_{t = 0}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!